# Civix: Install error: API error: DB Error: already exists

Tags: database, issues, civix

According documentation I created a skeleton module with civix and answered yes to install it. It then gives an error response as in the Title. Afterwards is listed active in the extensions page.

This is on 4.6.8 recently upgraded from 4.6.4.  Since the module seems active the error messsage is apparently not related to the installed module. When under Drupal I use the tool drush I got this more extensive error response even before creating/installing the skeleton module:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'API error: DB Error: already exists' in /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php:453              [error]
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(234): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->onApiError('RelationshipTyp...', 'create', Array, Array)
#1 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(179): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->insertNewEntity(Array)
#2 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(141): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcileEnabledModule(Object(CRM_Core_Module), Array)
#3 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(122): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcileEnabledModules()
#4 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(403): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcile()
#5 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(1407): CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches(true)
#6 [internal function]: civicrm_modules_enabled(Array)
#7 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/includes/module.inc(895): call_user_func_array('civicrm_modules...', Array)
#8 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/includes/module.inc(499): module_invoke_all('modules_enabled', Array)
#9 /home/c2/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment_7.inc(143): module_enable(Array)
#10 /home/c2/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/pm/pm.drush.inc(1120): drush_module_enable(Array)
#11 [internal function]: drush_pm_enable('help')
#12 /home/c2/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(368): call_user_func_array('drush_pm_enable', Array)
#13 /home/c2/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(219): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#14 [internal function]: drush_command('help')
#15 /home/c2/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(187): call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#16 /home/c2/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(62): drush_dispatch(Array)
#17 /home/c2/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(70): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#18 /home/c2/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(11): drush_main()
#19 {main}
```

When I look in the related ConfigAndLog I see:

```
Sep 08 14:14:08  [info] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(897): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: already exists", -5, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_relationship_type (name_a_b , label_a_b , name_b_a , labe...")
#4 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-5, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_relationship_type (name_a_b , label_a_b , name_b_a , labe...")
#5 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -5, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO civicrm_relationship_type (name_a_b , label_a_b , name_b_a , labe...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(929): DB_common->raiseError(-5, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1062 ** Duplicate entry 'Benefits Specialist is' for key 'UI_name_a_b'")
#7 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("INSERT INTO civicrm_relationship_type (name_a_b , label_a_b , name_b_a , labe...")
#9 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("INSERT INTO civicrm_relationship_type (name_a_b , label_a_b , name_b_a , labe...")
#10 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1060): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT INTO civicrm_relationship_type (name_a_b , label_a_b , name_b_a , labe...")
#11 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(450): DB_DataObject->insert()
#12 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/RelationshipType.php(126): CRM_Core_DAO->save()
#13 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/RelationshipType.php(62): CRM_Contact_BAO_RelationshipType::add((Array:11), (Array:1))
#14 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_relationship_type_create((Array:11))
#15 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(96): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#16 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->run("RelationshipType", "create", (Array:10), NULL)
#17 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(232): civicrm_api("RelationshipType", "create", (Array:10))
#18 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(179): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->insertNewEntity((Array:6))
#19 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(141): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcileEnabledModule(Object(CRM_Core_Module), (Array:4))
#20 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(122): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcileEnabledModules()
#21 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(403): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcile()
#22 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager.php(246): CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches(TRUE)
#23 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Extension.php(56): CRM_Extension_Manager->install((Array:1))
#24 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_extension_install((Array:3))
#25 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(96): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#26 /var/www/civicrm/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->run("Extension", "install", (Array:3), NULL)
#27 /home/c2/bin/civix.php/src/CRM/ClientBundle/class.api.php(228): civicrm_api("Extension", "install", (Array:3))
#28 /home/c2/bin/civix.php/src/CRM/ClientBundle/class.api.php(141): civicrm_api3->call("Extension", "install", (Array:1))
#29 /home/c2/bin/civix.php/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Command/InitCommand.php(101): civicrm_api3->__call("install", (Array:1))
#30 /home/c2/bin/civix.php/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Command/InitCommand.php(101): civicrm_api3->install((Array:1))
#31 /home/c2/bin/civix.php/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Command/InitCommand.php(80): CRM\CivixBundle\Command\InitCommand->tryEnable(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), "ipdp.relperms")
#32 /home/c2/bin/civix.php/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(238): CRM\CivixBundle\Command\InitCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#33 /home/c2/bin/civix.php/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(192): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 /home/c2/bin/civix.php/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(78): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#35 /home/c2/bin/civix.php/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(105): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#36 /home/c2/bin/civix.php/civix(22): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput))
#37 {main}


Sep 08 14:14:08  [info] $ManagedEntities_failed = Array
(
    [entity] => RelationshipType
    [action] => create
    [params] => Array
        (
            [version] => 3
            [name_a_b] => Benefits Specialist is
            [name_b_a] => Benefits Specialist
            [label_a_b] => Benefits Specialist is
            [label_b_a] => Benefits Specialist
            [description] => Benefits Specialist
            [contact_type_a] => Individual
            [contact_type_b] => Individual
            [contact_sub_type_a] => 
            [contact_sub_type_b] => 
        )

    [result] => Array
        (
            [error_code] => already exists
            [tip] => add debug=1 to your API call to have more info about the error
            [is_error] => 1
            [error_message] => DB Error: already exists
        )

)
```

What could be the cause and how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like the issue is happening during either the menu rebuild or (more likely) cache clearing.  Try doing a cache clear (**Administer menu > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and Update Paths**, press the "Cleanup Caches" button) and also rebuild the menu (example.org/civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1).  Does either one trigger the issue?  If so we can update the question to reflect that.

Comment: I have the same error. We use CiviCase on this site and relationships are setup correctly and suddenly we have this error. How do we get rid of this error? The error only happens on the test site and not on the live site. In the log file I see the following: Oct 27 11:34:09 [info] $ManagedEntities_failed = Array ( [entity] => RelationshipType [action] => create [params] => Array ( [version] => 3 [name_a_b] => Case Coordinator is [name_b_a] => Case Coordinator [label_a_b] => Case Coordinator is [label_b_a] => Case Coordinator [description] => Case Coordinator [contact_type_a] => Individual [con

Answer (score 2):

After posting my comment, I did a little bit of digging into what the `CRM_Core_ManagedEntities::reconcile` function does.  It says:

```
* Identify any enabled/disabled modules. Add new entities, update
* existing entities, and remove orphaned (stale) entities
```

So it would seem that it's confused because "Benefits Specialist Is" is a relationship associated with CiviCase, but perhaps you have it enabled with CiviCase disabled or vice versa.  Try enabling/disabling that relationship to match whether you use CiviCase and see if the error persists.

Comment: Error went away when disabling some unused demo cases. It's weird that Civicirm includes these even when I remember that during installation I decided not to enable the demo content. 

Thanks for leading me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened after upgrade from 4.6 to 5.1 and I had visit the Case Types config page, then remove the Case Roles mentioned in ConfigAndLog, saved the Case Type, then added them back in again.